# Recursive function for reversing a list is returning "None"

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, return-value, nonetype

I am trying to reverse a list in python using a recursive function.The python program given below takes three parameters an list `lst`, a starting index `start` from where the list is supposed to be reversed and an ending index `end`. But the function returns `None` and I am unable to understand why?

```
def reverse(lst,start,end):
    if start>=end:
        return lst
    else:
        temp=lst[start]
        lst[start]=lst[end]
        lst[end]=temp
        reverse(lst,start+1,end-1)
```

Comment: Change `reverse(lst,start+1,end-1)` to `return reverse(lst,start+1,end-1)`

Comment: Look at the `else` case.  It calls itself recursively, then discards the result and implicitly returns `None`.  To fix it, just add the missing `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from the else part too. As you know that the if part of recursive functions is generally the base condition which will most probably be the run in the last function call. So you need to return the answer from the previous function calls too.

```
def reverse(lst,start,end):
      if start>=end:
         return lst
      else:
        temp=lst[start]
        lst[start]=lst[end]
        lst[end]=temp
        return reverse(lst,start+1,end-1)
```

Comment: Sure. Actually, I didn't search for the question. Will take care next time @TomKarzes.